# Closure compiler export Typescript classes and functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, minify, google-closure-compiler, bundling-and-minification

I am trying to use closure compiler advanced mode on typescript generated classes with no success. Is there anyone who has accomplished such things.

Typescript Class

```
class TestData {
BlogName: string;
CacheTimeOut: number;
CopyrightHolder: string;

constructor(blogName: string, cacheTimeOut: number, copyrightHolder: string) {
    this.BlogName = blogName;
    this.CacheTimeOut = cacheTimeOut;
    this.CopyrightHolder = copyrightHolder;
}

addBlog(value: string): boolean {
    console.log('add blog');
    return true;
}

validate(): boolean {
    console.log('all valid');
    return true
}       
}

var myTestData = new TestData("name",22,"cpyright");
```

Generated Code

```
var TestData = (function () {
function TestData(blogName, cacheTimeOut, copyrightHolder) {
    this.BlogName = blogName;
    this.CacheTimeOut = cacheTimeOut;
    this.CopyrightHolder = copyrightHolder;
}
TestData.prototype.addBlog = function (value) {
    console.log('add blog');
    return true;
};
TestData.prototype.validate = function () {
    console.log('all valid');
    return true;
};
return TestData;

})();var myTestData = new TestData();
```

This compiles into

```
new function() {};
```

I understand I should provide exports, so I added

```
window['TestData'] = TestData;
window['TestData'].prototype['addBlog'] = TestData.prototype.addBlog
window['TestData'].prototype['validate'] = TestData.prototype.validate
```

my output from closure compiler advanced compilation is

```
var a = function() {
  function b() {
  }
  b.prototype.a = function() {
    console.log("add blog");
    return !0;
  };
  b.prototype.b = function() {
    console.log("all valid");
    return !0;
  };
  return b;
}();
window.TestData = a;
window.TestData.prototype.addBlog = a.prototype.a;
window.TestData.prototype.validate = a.prototype.b;
new a;
```

If you see there is still no constructor code that is left. This gets worse when we add this inside a module.

I also tried to use the @export of google closure wiht no success

[image: Google recommendations]

I see couple of pluggins which can generate closure compiler annotations based on typescript, but those also doesnt generate proper code.

[Thirdparty closure annotations generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-closure-compiler)

Comment: Closure compiler removes dead code. You can use goog.provide to export this class and goog.require to use it. But if you don't use it in any code it won't show in the compiled code

Comment: so it should be given to the generated code manually..?

Comment: I tried goog.provide('TestData'); still doesnt work

Comment: It seems wrong that the intermediate code example calls the constructor with no arguments: `var myTestData = new TestData();` if this passed arguments, wouldn't the Closure compiler keep the constructor?

Comment: If you use myTestData and or pass some values to the constructor you wil see more code. Closure compiler only compiles and optimizes code that's used. You can find how to specify and use library classes in the closure library documentation.

Comment: No it didnt unfortunately. I have tried passing arguments. Still the constructor is removed. I believe it is because of the module pattern that is emitted out of typescript which closure doesnt like.

Comment: have you tried invoking `.addBlog` on the dummy? I don't know how good the compiler is but just constucting a var that is never used, might as well be a noop

Comment: @anandaravindan it is removed in advanced mode because you never use those properties. If this is "all your code" it is correctly optimizing it - because you never need those values. If this is "some of your code" you need to be more conservative and use simple optimizations to avoid losing what may be used elsewhere.

Comment: @Steve Fenton. Understood. I used those variables inside the method blog and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @anandaravindan np - glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a very basic test of this. Perhaps you changed your code and haven't re-tried.

If you compile the TypeScript in your question, it should result in the following JavaScript:

```
var TestData = (function () {
    function TestData(blogName, cacheTimeOut, copyrightHolder) {
        this.BlogName = blogName;
        this.CacheTimeOut = cacheTimeOut;
        this.CopyrightHolder = copyrightHolder;
    }
    TestData.prototype.addBlog = function (value) {
        console.log('add blog');
        return true;
    };
    TestData.prototype.validate = function () {
        console.log('all valid');
        return true;
    };
    return TestData;
})();
var myTestData = new TestData("name", 22, "cpyright");
```

In particular, the last line passes arguments to the `TestData` constructor.

A quick run of this results in (white-space is mine) using `@compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS`:

```
var TestData=function(){
    function a(a,b,c){
        this.BlogName=a;this.CacheTimeOut=b;this.CopyrightHolder=c
    }
    a.prototype.addBlog=function(a){console.log("add blog");return!0};
    a.prototype.validate=function(){
        console.log("all valid");return!0
    };
    return a
}(),myTestData=new TestData("name",22,"cpyright");
```

If you use advanced optimizations on partial code, it will be too aggressive. You need to supply *all* of your code for the Closure compiler to understand what really isn't used.

If your example represents all of your code, you'll notice that the constructor along with all three properties (BlogName, CacheTimeOut, and CopyrightHolder) are genuinely never used, so can be removed without affecting the behaviour of the program.

Comment: I was talking about advanced compilation. Not white space.

Comment: The example above is simple optimization (not white-space). For advanced compilation to be an option for you - you need to supply all of your code to the compiler. It removed unused code, so it needs to know all of the code before it can correctly understand what is used. For example if you add a console log statement to show the value of `myTestData.BlogName`, suddenly that parameter is not removed, because it is used... `var b=new function(a){this.a=a}("name",22,"cpyright");console.log(b.a);`

Answer (score 1):

Answer: optimized noops are - wait for it - noops :)

Explanation:

If you use your gen code here http://www.closure-compiler.appspot.com/home 
with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS it produces:

```
new function(){};
```

if you add `myTestData.addBlog("test");` it produces:

```
(new (function(){function a(){}a.prototype.a=function(){console.log("add blog")};return a}())).a();
```

Comment: I got this. But why there is no code in the constructor

Comment: @anandaravindan because the compiler can tell you never use those values - so you don't need to accept them in the constructor, or store them.

Comment: because there is no code that does anything, what do you mean by `but why there is no code in the constructor`. As far as I understand it without externs the compiler sees your code as "thats all there is", and since you never use the var, it drops the constructor, then drops the whole "type" since none of it is needed, until "nothing" remains.

Comment: Is there anyway I can automate this
window['TestData'] = TestData;
window['TestData'].prototype['addBlog'] = TestData.prototype.addBlog
window['TestData'].prototype['validate'] = TestData.prototype.validate
I thought I can use @export comment. But it didnt work. I added the required base.js as well.

Comment: @anandaravindan, I don't understand, what is your overall goal ?